# ¿como ordenar una tabla por un segundo campo en caso que el 1er campo este repetido? en MVC de Asp.Net y VisualStudio2017

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, ordenamiento

Estoy usando **Visual Studio 2017** con **ASP.Net** y **MVC**. 
Donde estoy ordenando los campos de una tabla por un campo *Numero de convocatoria*.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var hojaArchivo = db.HojaArchivo.Include(h => h.HojaInicial).Include(h => h.Materia);
    return View(hojaArchivo.OrderBy(e=> e.HojaInicial.NumeroConvocatoria ));
}
```

Donde use el siguiente codigo en el controlador y pude ordenar por el campo *NumeroConvocatoria* 
y me fue muy bien, la pregunta esta en como ordenar en un segundo campo en caso que el primer capo sea igual.

[image: presentar la información ordenada]

La intención es ordenar los numeros del campo *Punto* si existen campos repetidos en el campo *Numero de Convocatoria*.

Trate de hacerlo usando una coma `,` pero me da un error.

[image: Error orden by]

He buscado en la documentación de **Microsoft** pero solo ordenan por un campo en:

> [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Por favor si tienen una idea les estare agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return View(hojaArchivo.OrderBy(e=> e.HojaInicial.NumeroConvocatoria ).ThenBy(e=>e.ElOtroParametro))
```

espero te sea de ayuda